# Error in Line 1 but not sure

Tags: mysql, php

```
$user_forum_sql = (!empty($forum_id)) ? " WHERE session_page = " .intval($forum_id) : '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name . $user_forum_sql;`
```

Comment: Chang this line(`$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name . $user_forum_sql;`), to (`$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $session_table_name . '"'.$user_forum_sql.'"';`)

Comment: now it just says an error has occurred http://royalreddevils.com/index.php

Comment: Then look at your log files to see what's wrong. This is off-topic here, please see the [help].

Comment: I posted it on the stack overflow forum and i applied shgnInc fix and it still doesnt work displays the same thing because it is occurring in line 1

Comment: You'll need to provide more details about what you're doing and what you think the problem is. Begin with rewriting the question title -- currently it makes very little sense.

Comment: Before running your sql syntax, echo the last syntax and put it here for debugging it. `echo $sql;`

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use SELECT * - query only needed columns
2. Use prepared statements
3. Post the whole error message (mysql_error)
4. Print the whole sql statement and run in manually against the server
5. mysql queries in php should not end with a semicolon

And get the php syntax right:

```
$user_forum_sql = (!empty($forum_id)) ? " WHERE session_page = " . intval($forum_id) : '';
$sql = "SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM " . $session_table_name . $user_forum_sql;
```